# Download files and folders as a ZIP file using C# doesn't work in Mac

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, zip

I'm using the following code to download a set of files and folders as a ZIP, which works great in a Windows, but not in a Mac

```
string SourceFolderPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(FolderPath, "Initial"); 
string SourceZip = System.IO.Path.Combine(UserTemp, nameFolder + ".zip");

            if (Directory.Exists(SourceFolderPath))
            {
                if (File.Exists(SourceZip)) { File.Delete(SourceZip); }
                ZipInfo zip = new ZipInfo(SourceZip);
                zip.Pack(SourceFolderPath, true, CompressionLevel.None, null);

                if (File.Exists(SourceZip))
                {
                    System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(SourceZip);
                    Response.ClearContent();
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", file.Name));
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
                    Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
                    this.EnableViewState = false;
                    Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
                    Response.Flush();
                    File.Delete(SourceZip);
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
```

When using a Mac, inside of the resultant ZIP the folders disappear, and the files which should be in folders are called like `images\picture1.png`

I'm using `Path.Combine` to get the folder's path, could be because of that?

```
string SourceFolderPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(FolderPath, "Initial"); 
string SourceZip = System.IO.Path.Combine(UserTemp, nameFolder + ".zip");
```

Any advice would be great. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using DotNetZip to create the zip file. Here is the code I used

```
    string SourceFolderPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(FolderPath, "Initial");

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", nameFolder + ".zip"));

    bool recurseDirectories = true;
    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        zip.AddSelectedFiles("*", SourceFolderPath, string.Empty, recurseDirectories);
        zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
    }
    Response.End();
```

No problem extracting the content from zip using a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using *.NET Framework 4.5* or newer you can do this using the highly-efficient ASP.NET native `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive` class, which should be fully compatible with any zip implementation you can find (Windows OS, MAC OS and so on).

Here’s a quick implementation sample using a MemoryStream and a couple of byte arrays representing two files:

```
byte[] file1 = GetFile1ByteArray();
byte[] file2 = GetFile2ByteArray();

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        var zipArchiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry("file1.txt", CompressionLevel.Fastest);
        using (var zipStream = zipArchiveEntry.Open()) zipStream.Write(file1, 0, file1.Length);
        zipArchiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry("file2.txt", CompressionLevel.Fastest);
        using (var zipStream = zipArchiveEntry.Open()) zipStream.Write(file2, 0, file2.Length);
    }
    return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/zip", "Archive.zip");
}
```

Depending on your scenario you can use it inside a MVC Controller returning an `ActionResult`, persist the `MemoryStream` to disk, replace it with a `FileStream` and so on: in the above example I used the [Controller.File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492897(v=vs.98).aspx) method (from **System.Web.Mvc** namespace) to return a [FileContentResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult(v=vs.98).aspx) object. If you're not using the MVC Framework you cannot do that, but you can still handle the `MemoryStream` in a different way - by using `Response.OutputStream` or other standard techniques.

For further info regarding this topic you can also [read this post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/create-zip-file-archive-programmatically-actionresult-asp-net-core-mvc-c-sharp/) on my blog.

Comment: Darkseal: what is the File here in return? It says File can not be used like a method

Comment: @MSIslam If you're using MVC, you have namespace conflicts between `System.IO.File` and `System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File`... just prepend the full namespace and you'll be fine. If you are not using the MVC Framework (or if you're outside a Controller), you need to handle the `MemoryStream` using alternative ways, such as `Response.OutputStream`: I updated my answer accordingly to better clarify that.

Comment: Response is showing doesn't exist in the current context. Using WebResponse, HttpResponse not helping